send USDT TRC20 by python
How can I send usdt trc20 to another address?
Here is what i tried to do:
USDT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t"
USDT_CONTRACT_ABI = [
    {
        "constant": False,
        "inputs": [
            {"name": "_to", "type": "address"},
            {"name": "_value", "type": "uint256"}
        ],
        "name": "transfer",
        "outputs": [{"name": "", "type": "bool"}],
        "payable": False,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
def send_usdt_transaction(sender_address,sender_private_key, receiver_address, amount, api_key):
    client = Tron(provider=HTTPProvider(api_key=api_key))

    private_key = PrivateKey(bytes.fromhex(sender_private_key))

    contract = Contract(
        addr=USDT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        bytecode="",
        name="USDT",
        abi=USDT_CONTRACT_ABI,
        client=client
    )

    amount_in_sun = int(amount * 1_000_000)

    txn = (
        contract.functions.transfer(receiver_address, amount_in_sun)
        .with_owner(sender_address)
        .fee_limit(50_000_000)
        .build()
        .sign(private_key)
    )

    txn_hash = txn.broadcast()


    return txn_hash


I have updated the code.
now I made this transaction https://tronscan.org/#/transaction/86c01587c17031328028506adb2db12244830b595ebfd7e157c587c28824b90d
But I get error: FAILED -OUT OF ENERGY>
as you can see I increased the fee_limit too

Did you ask some GenAI tool to write this code? It contains meaningful comments, but those completely deviate from the implementation... First of all, default "constructor" (client = Tron()) connects to mainnet - use Tron(network='nile') to connect to nile testnet. Second, .broadcast() does not wait for completion - it only waits for the request to complete, you probably also want to txn.wait(). Third, please don't print exceptions - there's no point in catching it here, just remove whole try...except block.

I'm also not certain that you can transfer TRX from your wallet to itself - sounds a bit strange. Consider creating a second wallet and send there instead. Your immediate error, even though you only print this balance instead of normal traceback, is "insufficient funds": since your wallet has nile testnet TRX, it likely doesn't have anything on mainnet, attempts to send TRX there will fail.

the code updated!
